# Android Virtual Device Emulate Camera with Static Image

Tags: android, camera, emulation, android-virtual-device

i am currently trying to emulate a static image on an AVD 
In the settings there are the 2 options:
-use computer webcam
-emulate

When checking emulate there is this moving rectangle but I believe there must be a possibility to replace this with a static image....!

Does anyone have an idea about it?

Thanks, John

Comment: Did you find anything related to this issue? I'm also looking for answer to this question.